Can a VSTO add in for MS Project show a UI besides the Ribbon?
TLDR; Can you give more real estate in VSTO to MS Project Desktop Add in then a little Ribbon control?
I was working for the first time with a VSTO add in and the tutorials I think are older which I expect, but even so I am not finding any help for the UI portion really:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-project?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp
I was able to put in a new item in my project and it shows fine

Ribbon (Visual Designer)

Is it possible to a larger area pane to show with VSTO?  I was looking at the tutorial and it just basically inserts a task and mentions nothing on the UI but the ribbon.  Is this all there is you can do graphically?  I just really wanted to give more real estate and do some dropdowns and buttons to call a service I made. I can do that but it looks very small:

Is there any way to at least give more real estate?  This is for a Project Professional Office 365 Desktop?  I have created a whole WPF User control and I thought I read you can wire that up but it never shows.  Do you have to do something with the

ThisAddIn.cs


I feel like I have read a lot of data, but have not found a simple tutorial on the UI portion of what Project can do.  I can do the Ribbon but I thought I read somewhere that the Add Ins can take a WPF or Winforms UserControl.  I just don't know how to wire it up.
As always, any help is much appreciated.

You cannot have it load up a WPF User Control UNLESS that is nested in Windows Form.  My WPF was working fine but there is no way without a parent body to host it.  There is no Main Windows WPF form for Project or any other main body element that I could see as all the other Add Ins for Word, Outlook, Excel etc have better eventing for UIs.
So you add a Windows Form, there isn't one by default.  You set the 'child' in the Properties pane of this form to be a user control in WPF for more modern design abilities of WPF.  Then you need a trigger like a button as you still need to use the ribbon unless you want to do something simple and use the startup, but then you cannot get it back.  Then it's similar to
var form = new Form1();
form.Show();

But you need to have know how to apply the Ribbon, make a Windows Form, set a control inside that.

Look into using Task Panels in your VSTO addin:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

Thanks but I think Project has a limitation as the 'this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(' is not available for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/office-ui-customization?view=vs-2022.  It shows it works for Outlook, Word, and Excel, yet not Project.  Ever worked on the 'Backstage-view' and know about that?

You are right, looks like Project does not work with Task Panes. Back Stage won't be that useful. You can always made a flowing window on top of the main window...

Interesting please elaborate if you don't mind.  I'm pretty senior to .NET, but very junior to Add Ins compared to you.  Do you mean I could add a control to the ribbon to make a larger UI?

No, I mean just create a regular WinForms or WPF form and make it the child of the main window.

I tried that and it never worked.  Do you mean drag and drop it on the ribbon or wire something up in the AppStart method?  My biggest problem is something I think should be simple I keep getting stopped on just it starting up.

No, I mean create a regular Form descendant that will float in front of the Office app.

I do that in the project and it never shows up.  I tried with WPF and it never starts.  So do I just do a new in the Startup code?

You really need to show the relevant snippet of you code

You can add a button in the ribbon and show your custom form when the user clicks on your button.
